# How to copy large number of small files to a NTFS external drive?

Tags: nautilus, ntfs, cp

I have a large number (15K+) of small files of size 3-4 KB each. What is the fastest method to copy those files to a NTFS drive?

I tried Nautilus and `cp`, but they are really slow.

Comment: What would you expect? IMHO it won't be faster... If the NTFS drive is connected through USB it will be even worse ;) Maybe you can compress them and copy to another drive then.

Comment: You can determine this yourself by using the time command as a prefix. For example `time cp *source* *destination*` where source is the source filemask and destination is the target.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can move them to *tape archive* (`*.tar`) and copy the archive to another drive then. It could possibly help you.

Compress:

```
 tar -cvf my-new-archive.tar dir-with-files-to-add/*
```

Decompress:

```
 tar -xf my-new-archive.tar dir-for-extract-files/*
```

Comment: honza-kasik is right: compress before you move it; that's if you have enough space on your original drive for the compressed file.